# How to change the login policy Using API in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

In DocuSign Application having Login policy for SSO when create a new User using admin account.But when creating User using API I do not have any Login policy field.can someone guide me how to create a user using Admin account using API with login policy with SSO.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can't. Organization Admin controls (including Login Policy) aren't yet exposed to the public API.